# Ruby generated grpc class service name conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, grpc

I have a strange situation where the message name is same as the generated class in my proto definition i.e., Service

for ex:
proto file

```
service Dummy {
rpc Register(RegisterServiceRequest) returns Service {}
}

message Service {
    string name = 1;
}
```

when I generate the grpc service it becomes

pb.rb file

```
module ...
  module ...
    class Service

      include GRPC::GenericService

      self.marshal_class_method = :encode
      self.unmarshal_class_method = :decode
      self.service_name = 'some.Dummy'


      rpc :Register, RegisterServiceRequest, Service
  
  end

    Stub = Service.rpc_stub_class
  end
end
```

when I try to run it is throwing below `argumenterror`

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.23.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/service.rb:126:in assert_can_marshal
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.23.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/service.rb:94:in`rpc'

how to fix the issue? is it possible to override the name of the `class Service` while generating the service pb.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clash is here:

```rb
# ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  service Dummy {
    ...
#         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  message Service
```

There is a domestic GRPC class `Service`. Rename yours to use somewhat like `message MessageService`.

Comment: is there no way around it? like providing some kind of flag to rename the GRPC class `Service` to something else